# Restrict logging for a particular child shell script

Tags: linux, shell, logging

I'm running a bunch of scripts through one main parent script. I have added logging code in the parent script like below:

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>logFileName 2>&1
```

This generates logs for all child scripts. I want to skip the log generation for one particular script, since its logs can be very heavy at times.

Is there any way to do this? Many thanks!

My parent script looks like this:

```
mkdir -p $scriptFolder/log
logFile="$scriptFolder/log/$(echo "$4" | tr -d '\n\r')_log_ImportMain_$dateTime.log"
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>$logFile 2>&1
source $scriptFolder/shellscripts/1.copyFilesFromFTP.sh
source $scriptFolder/shellscripts/2.import.sh
source $scriptFolder/shellscripts/3.export.sh
source $scriptFolder/shellscripts/4.copyFilesToFTP.sh
```

I want to skip logging for 3.export.sh, is there any way possible to do this?

Comment: The code you are showing does not tell us how you are running those scripts or how their logs are being produced.  If this is an orchestration script which runs all the others as subprocesses individually, discard standard error (and/or standard output) from the one you don't want output from.

Comment: The `trap` signals you enumerate are really weird.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I have a parent script which is simply calling all the child scripts. The above code is being used for generating logs. Before calling of child scripts, I have this log code in parent script. I just want to exclude log generation for on of the child scripts since its logs are heavy and I want just one log file for the overall process.

Comment: You are restating what's already in the question, and not clarifying anything.  The bounty here isn't helping much when we have to guess what your actual code looks like.  Please [edit] your question to show us what you are doing in the actual code you need help with.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: About the trap signals, I got the logging code from here.
http://serverfault.com/questions/103501/how-can-i-fully-log-all-bash-scripts-actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not running the scripts as subprocesses, which your question implies with the "parent" term, but anyway, you can have another redirection for that individual command, like this:

```
mkdir -p "$scriptFolder"log       # notice quoting
logFile="$scriptFolder/log/$(echo "$4" | tr -d '\n\r')_log_ImportMain_$dateTime.log"
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3 15  # notice addition of 15
exec 1>"$logFile" 2>&1            # notice quoting here, too
source $scriptFolder/shellscripts/1.copyFilesFromFTP.sh
source $scriptFolder/shellscripts/2.import.sh
# Temporarily disable logging for this source statement
source $scriptFolder/shellscripts/3.export.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
source $scriptFolder/shellscripts/4.copyFilesToFTP.sh
```

The `>/dev/null 2>&1` is in effect for the duration of the third `source` statement, and file descriptors are restored to their previous state when that finishes.

By the way, are you really sure `"$4"` can contain embedded newlines, and that you want to remove them in that case?  The trailing newline from `echo` will be trimmed off anyway, so perhaps you simply want `logfile="$scriptfolder/log/${4}_log_ImportMain_$dateTime.log"`

Comment: Thanks triplee.
About "$4", yes it can contain newlines.

Comment: If your script is a Bash script, still more economical to do something like `logFile="$scriptfolder/log/${4//$'[\r\n]'/}_log_ImportMain_$dateTime.log"`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that too. I'm still novice at shell scripting :)